# DropDownList VS. Submit/Search on HTML.Beginform

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, intranet

Summary: I'm building an application functionality to report missing data.  The different names with missing records populate my dropdown.  However, when I begin to search out the full report by that specific name (or any name) I have this error along with app crashing:

Error:  NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code.
Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

My View (Where the error is located):

VIEW:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", "POST"))
{
    <div class="searchField">
       <input type="text" class="search-query" name="heatSearch" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
    <br />
   <select>
    @foreach (var item in (ViewData["MissingChem"] as IEnumerable<string>))
    {
        <option> @item </option>
    }

   </select>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Session["InitialLoad"] = "Yes";
            HomeModel H = new HomeModel();
            ViewData["MissingChem"] = H.MissingQueryResults();
            return View();
        }
```

Model:

```
    public List<string> MissingQueryResults()
        {
            //HomeModel Tolerances = new HomeModel();
            List<String> nameList = new List<String>();

            SqlCommand missingQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT heatname FROM dbo.chemistrytable WHERE heatname NOT IN (SELECT heatname FROM dbo.chemistrytable WHERE sampletype = 'AVE') AND analysistime between '01-01-2013' and Current_Timestamp AND heatname LIKE '[a,b,c,d]%' Order by heatname");// + heatName + "'");
            SqlCommand mainquery = new SqlCommand("SELECT analysisv

alue.analysisid, heatname, analysistime, sampletype, grade, productid, element, value FROM dbo.AnalysisValue INNER JOIN dbo.ChemistryAnalysis ON dbo.AnalysisValue.AnalysisID = dbo.ChemistryAnalysis.AnalysisID Where heatname = '" + "' Order By analysisvalue.analysisid Asc, element");

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection))
        {
            missingQuery.CommandTimeout = 20000;//Dateadd(day, -1, Current_Timestamp)
            conn.Open();
            missingQuery.Connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
            missingQuery.Connection.Open();

            using (var reader = missingQuery.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        nameList.Add(reader[i].ToString().Trim());

                    }

                }
            }return nameList;
        }
    }
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you have a post action called "Index" in your "Home" controller that receives a model with the fields in your form?

I would go with the DropDownListFor approach, instead the ViewData approach, not making it the way you do.
So, in you controller, create a `SelectList` using the list of strings you get from `MissingQueryResults()`.

Note:The code was not tested, was written directly here.

**Model**
Create an viewModel with all the data you need to pass and the post to controller action:

```
public class VMHome {
 public SelectList MissingQueryResults {get; set;} // to build the dropdownList
 public string heatSearch {get; set;}
 public string MissingItem {get; set;}  //for posting selected value

}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
            Session["InitialLoad"] = "Yes";
            VMHome h = new VMHome();
            h.heatSearch = "";
            h.MissingQueryResults = new SelectList(H.MissingQueryResults())
            return View(h);
} 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(VMHome model)
{
            //do something with your posted data
            // may be adding search result to the viewmodel
            return View(model);
}
```

**In your view:**

```
@model VMHome
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", "POST"))
{
    <div class="searchField">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.heatSearch, new {placeholder = "Search", class = "search-query"} )
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MissingItem, Model.MissingQueryResults)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have one that takes the current Search terms. I didn't know that it would be pertinent to my problem, but I guess it was!